# Input box with drop down menu in Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium, python, and firefox to enter data into an input box on a website and select from a dropdown menu in the text box, but have been unable to do so. Formerly it was "just" a text box, but the website was changed.

The website is located at http://ecos.fws.gov/ecp/

the input textbox ID is "searchTerm". The site allows one to enter a scientific name (or part of a scientific name) and then select from options. For example, if you enter "Acipenser brevirostrum" into the textbox, it will provide you with a single option to click on.

Unfortunately, not sure how to code this up. Any help would be appreciated. So far I have this.

```
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("http://ecos.fws.gov/ecp")

SciName = driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm')
SciName.send_keys(names)
SciName.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The last three lines used to work, but now that it is both an input box with a drop down menu, it fails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the site is under the maintenance at the moment..

Comment: I noticed that, right after I posted my question. Just my luck. Thanks for looking at the question.

Comment: Can you share corresponding HTML code and the error trace??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you enter the name in the search box (id -- searchTerm), check for the visibility of the div (class -- autocomplete-suggestions) with an explicit wait. This contains the suggestions that the site throws up. Then you have to find the option which works for you. Try this xpath and click on the element. You should use `findelements` option as your text might not match anything and you will get an error.

```
"//div[@class='autocomplete-suggestion'][contains(.,'Acipenser brevirostrum')]"
```

If you have problems getting the autocomplete dropdown when you type the search text, send the text one character at a time with a small interval in between to trigger the call.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `driver.find_element_by_name`,as html is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" placeholder="Search ECOS">
```

This code will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://ecos.fws.gov/ecp/")

driver.find_element_by_name("query").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("query").send_keys("test")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-default").click()
```